# How to make an R function return multiple columns and append them to a data frame?

Tags: function, r, append, dataframe

Starting with this data frame

```
myDF = structure(list(Value = c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2)), .Names = "Value", row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Suppose I want to run this function on every row of myDF$Value

```
getNumberInfo <- function(x) {
if(x %% 2 ==0) evenness = "Even" else evenness="Odd"
if(x > 0) positivity = "Positive" else positivity = "NonPositive"
if (positivity == "Positive") logX = log(x) else logX=NA
c(evenness,positivity,logX)
}
```

... to get this data frame

```
structure(list(Value = c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), Evenness = c("Even", 
"Odd", "Even", "Odd", "Even"), Positivity = c("NonPositive", 
"NonPositive", "NonPositive", "Positive", "Positive"), Log = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "0", "0.693147180559945")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), .Names = c("Value", 
"Evenness", "Positivity", "Log"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to change your `getNumberInfo` function to return a list rather than a vector, so that the values can have different types.  As it is, they're all being cast to strings, which probably isn't what you want for `logX`.

```
getNumberInfo <- function(x) {
  if(x %% 2 ==0) evenness = "Even" else evenness="Odd"
  if(x > 0) positivity = "Positive" else positivity = "NonPositive"
  if (positivity == "Positive") logX = log(x) else logX=NA
  list(evenness,positivity,logX)
}
```

Furthermore, you can use the names to a somewhat better effect so that you don't have to repeat them:

```
getNumberInfo <- function(x) {
  list(evenness = if(x %% 2 ==0) "Even" else "Odd",
       positivity = if(x > 0) "Positive" else "NonPositive",
       logX = if(x > 0) log(x) else NA)
}
```

Then the solution becomes simple:

```
> cbind(myDF, t(sapply(myDF$Value, getNumberInfo)))
  Value evenness  positivity      logX
1    -2     Even NonPositive        NA
2    -1      Odd NonPositive        NA
3     0     Even NonPositive        NA
4     1      Odd    Positive         0
5     2     Even    Positive 0.6931472
```

Finally, if you use `ifelse` (which can work on vectors) instead of `if`, it gets even simpler because you don't have to call `apply`:

```
getNumberInfo <- function(x) {
  list(evenness = ifelse(x %% 2 ==0, "Even", "Odd"),
       positivity = ifelse(x > 0, "Positive", "NonPositive"),
       logX = ifelse(x > 0, log(x), NA))
}

> cbind(myDF, getNumberInfo(myDF$Value))
  Value evenness  positivity      logX
1    -2     Even NonPositive        NA
2    -1      Odd NonPositive        NA
3     0     Even NonPositive        NA
4     1      Odd    Positive 0.0000000
5     2     Even    Positive 0.6931472
```

That last solution emits a warning, because it's actually computing the log of every element, not just those with `x>0`.  Not sure the most elegant way to deal with that.

Comment: What does `t(sapply`do as opposed to just `tapply`? I don't know what wrapping something with `t()` does. I've never seen it documented.

Comment: t() transposes (for example, changes a row to a column, or vice versa).

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
 out <- cbind(myDF, t(apply(myDF, 1, getNumberInfo)))
 colnames(out) <- c('Value', 'Evenness', 'Positivity', 'Log')
```

Which gives you:

```
  Value Evenness  Positivity               Log
1    -2     Even NonPositive              NA
2    -1      Odd NonPositive              NA
3     0     Even NonPositive              NA
4     1      Odd    Positive                 0
5     2     Even    Positive 0.693147180559945
```

Comment: What does `t(apply`do as opposed to just `tapply`? I don't know what wrapping something with `t()` does. I've never seen it documented.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```
> library(plyr)
> df <- mdply(myDF, getNumberInfo)
> names(df) <- c('Value', 'Evenness', 'Positivity', 'Log')
> df
  Value Evenness  Positivity       Log
1    -2     Even NonPositive        NA
2    -1      Odd NonPositive        NA
3     0     Even NonPositive        NA
4     1      Odd    Positive 0.0000000
5     2     Even    Positive 0.6931472
```