# Apply a function in R on each row: function takes multiple columns from each row and returns multiple new columns

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

The general idea of this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594477/r-apply-function-returning-multiple-values-to-each-row-of-data-frame-and-add-the)

However the answer did not work in my specific case since I want to use a third input into the function, which is a large dataframe. I have also tried using sapply as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395156/how-to-make-an-r-function-return-multiple-columns-and-append-them-to-a-data-fram) but that still does not work.

My goal is to avoid having to create the new columns by hand/use a for loop to append into the new columns. Is this possible in R? Is there another more 'R' way to structure my data and/or function? I looked at `purrr::pmap` but I don't know how to have it output multiple columns

Here is my minimal reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

find_sample_gaps<-function(site, analyte, df){
  
  Sample <- df%>%
    filter(site_code == site)%>%filter(analyte_code == analyte)%>%
    mutate(Year = as.numeric(format(Date, '%Y')))
  
  x<-Sample%>%
    group_by(Year)%>%
    summarize(n_samples = length(Year))
  
  gaps<-which(c(1,diff(x$Year))>1)
  
  a<-sum(x$n_samples) 
  b<-length(unique(Sample$Date))
  c<-'No gaps'
  
  if(length(gaps)>0){ 
    c<-paste('There are', as.character(gaps), 'gaps')
  }
  
  return(cbind(a,b,c))
}

# use function inside cbind to add columns to dataframe

result<-cbind(output1, find_sample_gaps(output1$site_code, output1$analyte_code, output2)) # throws error because output2 dataframe isn't the same size as result?

# another attempt also using cbind with sapply

result<-cbind(output1, t(sapply(c(output1$site_code, output1$analyte_code, output2), find_sample_gaps))) # also throws error, does not recognize the inputs into the function?
```

Here is my input data:

```
output1<-structure(list(site_code = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "j", "k", "k", "k", "k", 
"k", "k", "k", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", 
"q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "x", "x", 
"x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "aa", 
"aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb", "bb", 
"cc", "cc", "cc", "cc", "cc", "dd", "dd", "dd", "dd", "dd", "ee", 
"ee", "ee", "ee", "ee", "ee", "ee", "ff", "ff", "ff", "ff", "ff", 
"gg", "gg", "gg", "gg", "gg", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", 
"ii", "ii", "ii", "ii", "ii", "ii", "jj", "jj", "jj", "jj", "jj", 
"jj", "jj"), analyte_code = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "f", "g", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
"a", "f", "g", "c", "d", "e", "a", "f", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "d", "e", "a", "f", "g", "d", "e", 
"a", "f", "g", "a", "f", "g", "d", "e", "a", "f", "g", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "a", "f", "g", "d", "e", "a", "f", "g", "d", "e", "a", 
"f", "g", "d", "e", "a", "f", "g", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "f", 
"g", "d", "e", "a", "f", "g", "d", "e", "a", "f", "g", "c", "d", 
"e", "a", "f", "g", "c", "d", "e", "a", "f", "g", "b", "c", "d", 
"e", "a", "f", "g")), row.names = c(NA, -115L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
output2<-structure(list(site_code = c("dd", "k", "k", "r", "aa", "ii", 
"y", "l", "l", "l", "q", "cc", "w", "bb", "c", "ff", "m", "ii", 
"p", "ff", "ff", "z", "ff", "l", "w", "hh", "ff", "ff", "ff", 
"k", "j", "bb", "x", "hh", "jj", "z", "dd", "q", "aa", "k", "bb", 
"r", "e", "j", "j", "ii", "y", "hh", "p", "p", "u", "gg", "ff", 
"p", "cc", "u", "dd", "n", "bb", "bb", "aa", "ff", "x", "k", 
"w", "x", "j", "bb", "cc", "ii", "hh", "jj", "b", "hh", "y", 
"u", "cc", "hh", "aa", "b", "jj", "hh", "gg", "y", "r", "a", 
"aa", "aa", "z", "ff", "ee", "g", "hh", "hh", "cc", "hh", "hh", 
"h", "l", "k"), analyte_code = c("e", "b", "b", "c", "f", "d", 
"a", "a", "a", "d", "f", "c", "g", "a", "a", "e", "a", "e", "a", 
NA, "c", "a", "d", "c", "d", "b", "a", "f", "a", "g", "b", "c", 
"f", "f", "c", "a", "f", "a", "e", "g", "c", "a", "a", "b", "e", 
"a", "e", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "e", "a", "f", "a", 
"a", "a", "c", "e", "a", "e", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "e", "c", 
"a", "a", "g", "c", "a", "b", "b", "f", "b", "e", "d", "d", "c", 
"c", "a", "a", "b", "f", "f", "b", "a", "e", "g", "c", "a", "a", 
"a", "e", "d"), Date = structure(c(13326, 14287, 14403, 17669, 
16330, 18603, 17428, 15502, 18708, 13780, 17757, 18582, 18087, 
18582, 17433, 13326, 17674, 13668, 18059, 17966, 16701, 17142, 
14915, 16861, 13999, 15502, 15412, 16856, 14551, 18708, 12128, 
14314, 13326, 12563, 13780, 17224, 17611, 15703, 16239, 13780, 
12970, 16096, 16544, 17134, 18603, 13780, 18388, 15684, 19157, 
18684, 17449, 18857, 15075, 18746, 12683, 15618, 17142, 18634, 
15601, 17065, 15926, 12970, 17611, 16692, 13943, 12871, 16958, 
13263, 13451, 16179, 13094, 15044, 18131, 12212, 15966, 16410, 
14775, 13283, 16239, 16391, 17050, 13283, 16085, 16330, 17362, 
18393, 18087, 13724, 14396, 14396, 17331, 19106, 14215, 13388, 
14088, 18241, 18143, 17187, 13486, 12482), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you add a frame with your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this give you what you are after?  Note I changed the return of the function to be a list.

```
find_sample_gaps<-function(site, analyte, df){
    
    Sample <- df%>%
        filter(site_code == site)%>%filter(analyte_code == analyte)%>%
        mutate(Year = as.numeric(format(Date, '%Y')))
    
    x<-Sample%>%
        group_by(Year)%>%
        summarize(n_samples = length(Year))
    
    gaps<-which(c(1,diff(x$Year))>1)
    
    a<-sum(x$n_samples) 
    b<-length(unique(Sample$Date))
    c<-'No gaps'
    
    if(length(gaps)>0){ 
        c<-paste('There are', as.character(gaps), 'gaps')
    }
    
    comb <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c)
    
    return(comb)
}

output3 <- output1 %>%
    mutate(a = find_sample_gaps(site, analyte, all_of(output2))$a,
           b = find_sample_gaps(site, analyte, all_of(output2))$b,
           c = find_sample_gaps(site, analyte, all_of(output2))$c) 

output3
   site_code analyte_code     a     b c      
   <chr>     <chr>        <int> <int> <chr>  
 1 a         a                1     1 No gaps
 2 b         a                1     1 No gaps
 3 c         a                1     1 No gaps
 4 d         a                1     1 No gaps
 5 e         a                1     1 No gaps
 6 f         a                1     1 No gaps
 7 g         a                1     1 No gaps
 8 h         a                1     1 No gaps
 9 i         a                1     1 No gaps
10 j         b                1     1 No gaps
```